# How to define the variable and use in jenkins through windows batch command

Tags: windows, batch-file, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

windows batch command in jenkins

how can i print jobName inside bat command using jenkinsfile ?

```
script {
     jobName = JOB_NAME 
     echo jobName  #its printing job name
     bat 'echo jobName' #its not printing job name 
     bat 'echo $jobName' #its not printing job name
     bat 'echo "$jobName"' #its not printing job name
}
```

Or

how can i take JOB_NAME using jenkinsfile ?

```
script {
     bat '''
     set jobName = JOB_NAME  // could not find job name
     echo jobName  #its not printing job name
     echo "%jobName%"  #its not printing job name
     echo 'jobName'  #its not printing job name
     '''
}
```

Comment: `set jobName = JOB_NAME` allocates the string content, `<space>JOB_NAME` to a variable named `jobName<space>` so you should use `%jobName %` or preferably define the variable properly, i.e. `Set "jobName=JOB_NAME"`.

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins job parameters are not automatically propagated to shell children. 
Things to try:

1. backslash-escaping the dollar-sign
2. enclose the var-name in curly-braces
3. review https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/tour/environment/
4. try `withEnv`
5. use native Jenkinsfile `echo "blah"` (or Groovy `println "blah"`) instead of `sh 'echo blah'`

Comment: What you mentioned above is a shell script. but I am looking for a batch command using jenkinsfile .

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking, you need to use `%VAR%` when you are using it with `bat`. So basically:

```
bat '''
   echo "%jobName%"
'''
```

which is something OP has done, but it probably didn't work because the variable wasn't assigned correctly.